# Ordered list of joint parameters for Baxter

Tags: ros, joint-trajectory-action, rosparam, baxter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to adapt the code in [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/pr2_controllers/Tutorials/Moving%20the%20arm%20using%20the%20Joint%20Trajectory%20Action) for moving an arm using Joint Trajectory Action; they use PR2 and it's written in C++, I'm using Baxter and my code is in Python.  They have a command that lists all the joints and the order the parameters should be in: `rosparam get /r_arm_controller/joints` which displays

`[r_shoulder_pan_joint, r_shoulder_lift_joint, r_upper_arm_roll_joint, r_elbow_flex_joint, r_forearm_roll_joint, r_wrist_flex_joint, r_wrist_roll_joint]`

What is the analagous command for Baxter? When I do `rosparam list` I see essentially a controller for each individual joint. I want to get the ordered list of all joints so I can specify waypoints correctly.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243211/ordered-list-of-joint-parameters-for-baxter/) by [adamconkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/27913/adamconkey/) on ROS Answers with karma: 642 on 2016-09-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The short answer to your question is

```
rosparam get robot_config/<side>_config/joint_names
```

where  is either **left** or **right**, depending on your arm of interest.

The longer answer is that Baxter's interface allows for you to specify the joints in the order that you desire when commanding a JointCommand:
https://github.com/RethinkRobotics/baxter_common/blob/master/baxter_core_msgs/msg/JointCommand.msg

```
int32 mode
float64[] command
string[]  names

int32 POSITION_MODE=1
int32 VELOCITY_MODE=2
int32 TORQUE_MODE=3
int32 RAW_POSITION_MODE=4
```

Simply populate the `joint_names` array in the same order that you populate your `command` array, eg.

**Python**

```
from baxter_core_msgs.msg import JointCommand
...
cmd = JointCommand()
cmd.mode = JointCommand.POSITION_MODE
cmd.names = ["right_s0", "right_s1", "right_e0", "right_e1", "right_w0", "right_w1", "right_w2"]
cmd.command = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

**C++**

```
#include <baxter_core_msgs/JointCommand.h>
...
baxter_core_msgs::JointCommand cmd;
cmd.mode = baxter_core_msgs::JointCommand.POSITION_MODE
cmd.names.push_back("left_s0");
cmd.names.push_back("left_s1");
cmd.names.push_back("left_e0");
cmd.names.push_back("left_e1");
cmd.names.push_back("left_w0");
cmd.names.push_back("left_w1");
cmd.names.push_back("left_w2");
cmd.command.resize(cmd.names.size());
for(size_t i = 0; i < cmd.names.size(); i++)
  cmd.command[i] = 0.0;
```

Admittedly in both of those examples, I preserved the joint ordering from proximal to distal, but that is not necessary. The commands are reordered based on joint names once they are received by the MotorController.

---

Originally posted by [imcmahon](https://answers.ros.org/users/499/imcmahon/) with karma: 790 on 2016-09-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1